# Magento 2.X: Execute a portion of js file only when customer is logged in

Tags: magento2

```
 html += this + '<div class="dropD"><strong>i</strong></div>' +
                        '<div class="rect" id="futureDates">' + table +
                        '</div>' +
```

I have this code within .js file but I want to run this div only when customer is logged in. This div executes in frontend while viewing products PLease suggest some ways.

Answer (score 5):

Plese check with below code to check customer is logged in or not and add your html code..

**if you want to add below code in phtml file than replace 'define' to require**

```
    define(['jquery','Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'], function ($,customer) {
        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            alert('loggedin')
        } else{
            alert('loggedout')
        }
});
```

Comment: it didnot work.

Comment: let me check again...

Comment: please check, i update my answer. its working my side

Comment: every time show alert('loggedout') 
Even user login .

Comment: try to check with var customer = customer.get('customer'); console.log(customer());

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: customer.get is not a function

Comment: for above code is working, if you are using this code in phtml than replace define insted of require

Comment: Thank u it's working on checkout page